# Visual Studio Error Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file

Tags: visual-studio

Can anyone help how to solve this error in visual studio...

```
Error       Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 128724 > 65536 ; # fields: 98753 > 65536). 
Try supplying a main-dex list       
C:\Users\de\Downloads\timeline\Timeline_V2.7.1\statusapp\D8
```

Answer (score 0):

Check "multiDex" in the .Android project properties.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).